# SAX parser takes a lot of time to parse

Tags: android, saxparser

I have created an application where I parse data from server using SAX parser. I followed [this link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser)

It works fine but it took a lot of time. I need to reduce time taken to parse stuff.
Any pro-tips?

Comment: Post your SAX parsing code, otherwise... well it's a *teensy* bit hard to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious tip is: profile your code and determine where the time is going. Perhaps you are doing a lot of work handling some of the SAX events. Perhaps the time is being spent doing something entirely unrelated to the parsing. You can't tell until you profile.

Answer (score 2):

Like Ted said, [profile your code](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html).

Are you sure its the parse time and not the load time? Are you on wifi or a mobile network? How quickly are other apps loading their data?

That said, don't use that many `ArrayList` objects, a single array list with a custom container type (i.e. a Ticket object has a price and date, no need to have a price array and date array).

Check you memory usage, usually if things are slow you are generating a ton of garbage. (look for the GC in the log)

Use the `final` keyword for String parameters that won't change. So `setString(final String s)` instead of `setString(String s)`. This should prevent the Strings from being duplicated when passed as parameters.

Use JSON instead of XML if you can, its more light weight.

After you've made any significant change, [profile your code](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) again

Comment: Using `final` doesn't affect anything at run time. (The byte code for the compiled method will be identical with and without `final` parameter modifiers.) In any event, Strings are never duplicated when passed as parameters; the method receives a reference to the same String object that exists in the calling code. Perhaps you're thinking of another language?

Comment: @Ted Interesting, didn't know that about the final keyword. They do all seem to blend together :P